# How to form a sql query to fetch user object from table news which has row user_id

Tags: php, mysql, sql, key

I need to display the username of user which posted certain news post but I am not able to fetch user as an object i have these two tables

This is users table [image]

And this is news table which has user_id foreign key that points to id row from users table
[image]

I've tried this query

```
SELECT users.id, users.username FROM news INNER JOIN users ON news.user_id=users.id
```

But is only returning an array and i want an object to be returned (User object)

I am working with MVC handmade framework and i have controller view model and database this is a database part

```
 public function all() {
        $this->execute();
        return $this->statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
    }
```

this is model part

```
public function showUser(){

    $this->db->query("SELECT users.id, users.username FROM news INNER JOIN users ON news.user_id=users.id");
    return $this->db->all();


}
```

and this is controller part

```
 public function index(){

    $data = [

        'news' => $this->newsModel->all(),
        'users'=> $this->newsModel->showUser()

    ];


$this->view('users/news',$data);


}
```

Comment: show us what you've tried so far and which part in that is not working?

Comment: @JitendraYadav okay i edited the question.

Comment: it would be great if you can add `php` code to your question. Just a hint https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-object.php

Comment: i added that also @JitendraYadav

Comment: This is not simple php, you must be using some framework, please add that to tag and also add sufficient info, so one can help you by looking at it.